# If statement code break

Tags: java, if-statement

please how can i write the below code so that it works?
I have three ifs in my method, sometimes two of them are true, sometimes one of them is true, sometimes all of them are true. What can i replace in "nothing_of_above" so if none of the ifs are true the last condition will execute?

```
public void my_method(){

    if (a==1) {
        y++;
    }

    if (b==5) {
        y++;
    }

    if (c==10) {
        y++;
    }

    if (nothing_of_above){
        y=0;
    }

}
```

Comment: if ( a or b or c and u ... ) then; else if(d or e ...) then; else;

Comment: my mistake... I changed the code.
if i use ||(or) then one of three statements will happen, sometimes they happen all, sometimes y=1, sometimes y=2 and sometimes y=3

Comment: My friend please read this page and you will find solution by yourselft ,happy coding : [switch-if else](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: Thanks my friend but my condition is complicated...
(instead of (a==1) i have (my_array[x - 1][y - 1].equals("K") && array[x - 2][y - 2].equals("L")) and the others too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i used this

```
pointer = true;

public void my_method(){

    if (a==1) {
        y++;
        pointer = false;
    }

    if (b==5) {
        y++;
        pointer = false;
    }

    if (c==10) {
        y++;
        pointer = false;
    }

    if (pointer){
        y=0;
    }

}
```